# Render component after getting value from AsyncStorage in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

My React Component stores user's settings in the AsyncStorage and get's them on load. The storing and getting data works well, but there is a problem that components renders before the values has been got from the async function. How this could be fixed? This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { Media } from '../constants';

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const settings = ['appLanguage', 'colorTheme'];
    for(const i of settings) {
      this.getData(i).then(
        value => {
          if(value === null || value === undefined) {
            this.state[i] = Media.initalSettings[i];
          }
          else {
            this.state[i] = value;
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }

  async storeData(key, value) {
    try {
      if(key[0] != '@') {
        key = '@' + key;
      }
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    } 
    catch(e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
  }

  async getData(key) {
    try {
      if(key[0] != '@') {
        key = '@' + key;
      }
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      return value;
    } 
    catch(e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
  }

  render() {

    const { appLanguage } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <View>
          {appLanguage}
        </View>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default SettingsScreen;
```

Comment: I would have default values in the component, then pass them in once the async function is complete.  This way it will re-render once they get updated.

Comment: In general, if you don't get the required params for a component before rendering it, you should probably use a conditional rendering in that component (i.e. check if the required params are present, if they are, render normally, if they're not, render a loading or null)

Comment: @rhigdon, I've tried to move `this.state[i] = Media.initalSettings[i]` before calling the async function, but nothing has changed

Comment: You should never set the state directly.  You should use the setState helper function.

Comment: @rhigdon, thank for your advice, I though that calling setState is forbidden in the component's constructor, but I changed `this.state[i] = value` to `this.setState({key: value})` after getting the data and it worked right. You can write an answer and I'll mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set the state directly in the constructor.  Try this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const settings = ['appLanguage', 'colorTheme'];
    for(const i of settings) {
      this.getData(i).then(
        value => {
          if(value === null || value === undefined) {
            this.state[i] = Media.initalSettings[i];
          }
          else {
            this.setState({key: value})
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Here is some documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Answer (score 1):

your constructor is way too cluttered.

initialize an empty state variable and populate it when page loads

```js
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  
  this.state = {
    storedValue = ""
  }
}

async componentDidMount() {
  const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("settings");
  this.setState({storedValue})
}

render(){
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{storedValue}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```